# Three UUID's for a BLE device without services, is that possible?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Why do I find three UUID's with the "Light Blue" App, if there aren't any services? Is it possible, that there are only characteristics, without services?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently saw the same results with that app (LightBlue) while testing a BLE profile on my development board.

What I noticed is that depending on the way that the UUIDs are set up, sometimes that app could recognize that there was a peripheral device with a BLE profile, but then would report no services within. When I interrogated the peripheral, the "service" of my profile would be lumped together with the characteristics.

My suspicion is that the Apple TV you are looking at does indeed have a BLE service, but as the LightBlue app is categorizing the information it somehow misses that service, but can correctly see the characteristics within.

Finally, on a related note, if you are implementing your own BLE Handler code on iOS, then you should limit the services that you are looking for. For instance, if you had something along the lines of:

```
centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
```

in your Swift code (which I suspect LightBlue does), consider replacing that first nil argument with the CBUUID of the service you are looking for.  Strange, buggy things happen when you do a sweep of ALL BLE services in your vicinity.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

```
var bleCentralManager:CBCentralManager!

@IBAction func btnScan(_ sender: UIButton){

     //for scan peripheral(BLE) device
   self.bleCentralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
}
```